# Elasticsearch find documents by another document

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to search documents in elasticsearch which have exactly same fields as the given document of id docId. For e.g. user calls the api with a docId, I want to filter docs such that all the docs returned fulfills some parameters in docId.

For example can I query Elasticsearch like this:

```
POST similarTerms/_search
{
    "fields": [
       "_id", "title"
    ]   ,
    "filter": {
    "query": {"match": {
       "title": doc[docId].title
    }}
    }, 
    "size": 30

}
```

I know I can fetch the document with docId and then I can prepare the above query, but can I avoid the network hop somehow as even milliseconds of time improvement is of great concern for my app.

Thanks

Comment: I have the exact problem you had, if there is a way to fetch docId and use it to iterate in your query mentioned above I can solve mine. Did you find a way to fetch the docId and use it in your query above. If you did can please share it with me?

Answer (score 1):

This is a text-book scenario for "more like this" api. Quote from [the docs](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-more-like-this.html):

> The more like this (mlt) API allows to get documents that are "like" a
>   specified document. Here is an example:
>
> `$ curl -XGET
>   'http://localhost:9200/twitter/tweet/1/_mlt?mlt_fields=tag,content&min_doc_freq=1'`
>
> The API simply results in executing a search request with moreLikeThis
>   query (http parameters match the parameters to the more_like_this
>   query). This means that the body of the request can optionally include
>   all the request body options in the search API (aggs, from/to and so
>   on). Internally, the more like this API is equivalent to performing a
>   boolean query of more_like_this_field queries, with one query per
>   specified mlt_fields.

If you plan testing this (like I did) with one document only for test, make sure you also set `min_term_freq=0` and `min_doc_freq=0`: `GET /my_index/locations/1/_mlt?min_term_freq=0&min_doc_freq=0`

Comment: Can I filter more like this based on document being searched? Can I say return me only doc which have value of a particular fields exactly as the value of the doc being passed.