# What is the ElasticSearch equivalent for an SQL subquery?

Tags: elasticsearch

Can you nest queries logically in ElasticSearch, so the output of one query is the input to another query.
Another, way to ask is how can I chain or pipe queries together?

This should be analogous to the IN operator or subqueries in SQL

i.e.:-
select au_lname, au_fname, title from 
     (select au_lname, au_fname, au_id from pubs.dbo.authors
          where state = 'CA')
or

SELECT Name
FROM AdventureWorks2008R2.Production.Product
WHERE ListPrice =
    (SELECT ListPrice
     FROM AdventureWorks2008R2.Production.Product
     WHERE Name = 'Chainring Bolts' );

Comment: Maybe (to be tested) subqueries are now supported, considering the [Elasticsearch 6.3 release (June 2018) comes with native SQL support](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50889538/6309).

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Elasticsearch doesn't support subqueries; you would need to perform your first query, then construct a second query using the results of the first query as an input.

Comment: weeps, you're right.

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/application-joins.html

Answer (score 0):

this is not supported in elastic-search you must normalize your data and have all field you need in one setting

Answer (score -3):

That is totally correct, you must programm a subquery in your favorite programming language. An example can be found here:

https://sebastianviereck.de/elasticsearch-subquery-scoring-optimization/