# Elasticsearch - Subqueries and reusing the queries

Tags: elasticsearch

How we can achieve subqueries ( from SQL ) with elasticsearch?
And also, how we can reuse the queries or build the queries based on the results of the other queries ?

I didn't seem to find an references with respect to this in documentation,

One option is query template but it assumes to supply a query template and parameterize the values based on the need which might not be suitable for subqueries or reusing the queries in different places

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it seems this is the closest answer I see so far for this question.

**NO SUPPORT**

Hopefully, it is true with current version too ( 7.8.x)

[What is the ElasticSearch equivalent for an SQL subquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28734436/what-is-the-elasticsearch-equivalent-for-an-sql-subquery)